# @Html.EditorFor para propriedade DateTime remover hh:mm:ss

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Em minha *model* tenho um campo `DateTime` chamado *DataReferencia*, formatei com `Attributes`, porém quando estou na *view* está preenchendo `hh:mm:ss` Quero apenas a data *29/02/2016*.

**Model**

```
[Column("sdt_DataReferencia")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
[Display(Name = "Referência 01/mm/aaaa")]
public DateTime DataReferencia { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Boletos.DataReferencia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Boletos.DataReferencia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = Model.Boletos.DataReferencia }, })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Boletos.DataReferencia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Visualização

Crie em `Views\Shared` o diretório `DisplayTemplates`.

Dentro dele, crie uma *View* vazia chamada `DateTime.cs`.

Dentro desta *View*, coloque o seguinte:

```
@model DateTime?

@if (Model.HasValue)
{
    @Convert.ToDateTime(Model).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
}
```

Todos os `@Html.DisplayFor()` serão exibidos sem a hora.

---

### Edição

#### Alternativa 1: `TexBoxFor`

Use da seguinte forma:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cliente.DataReferencia, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Data de Referência" })
```

#### Alternativa 2: Campo `Date`

Este usa o `input Date` nativo do navegador. Nem sempre é uma boa alternativa porque alguns `input`s de navegadores conhecidos são bem ruins.

Altere esta anotação:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

Para:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
```

Logo abaixo, adicione:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
```

Não precisa alterar o `@Html.EditorFor`.

Comment: a primeira é bem interessante, mas como vou utilizar hh:mm:ss em algumas views então vou pela Alternativa 1

Comment: também tive que tirar do Html.EditFor o  @Value = Model.ValidadeDoCreditos, isso tb fazia vir os valores errado